# Display Google Map does not show in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

I added a google Map in asp.net application. But running the application, sometimes the Map displayed and sometimes too it doesn't display. I can't find the problem causing that malfunctioning of the application.

Here is the source code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    var markers = [
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
                {
                    "Network": '<%# Eval("Network") %>',
                    "lat": '<%# Eval("GPSLat") %>',
                    "lng": '<%# Eval("GPSLong") %>',
                    "Localite": '<%# Eval("Localite") %>'

                }
 </ItemTemplate>
 <SeparatorTemplate>,
 </SeparatorTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>];
  </script>



<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        };

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.Network 
            });
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent('<b>Reseau:</b> ' + data.Network + '<br/> <b>Localite:</b>' + data.Localite);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is the method that bind the repeater from from the web service method:

```
MediaWayBackEndService.BMBackEndServiceClient backEndService = new MediaWayBackEndService.BMBackEndServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IBMBackEndService");
            rptMarkers.DataSource = backEndService.GetKilometricNetwork(network, value).Tables[0];
            rptMarkers.DataBind();
```

This is the output of the application when it works fine and when it does not work fine.

[image]

[image]

Localhost liks cant be opend from other users!

Based on the console, i have found 1 errors:

```
Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Try to isolate the problem to either the browser, your ASP application, or the service you're calling. Save the page to see if it works when you open it, and test your service independently (may want to try Fidler or Postman to monitor and mimic requests)

Comment: @aardila i updated the post to show the result.

Comment: @nimeshjm i updated the post to show the result. In the tow cases i have the set of data in the first tab, meaning that the webservice return the data

Comment: Can you open developer tools in your browser (F12) and look in the "console" tab and check if there are any errors?

Comment: I think one of the possible reason is: the data in "rptMarkers" isn't ready yet when the javascript is parsed, so when the markers load, it is unable to read the markers, so the map isn't displayed correctly

Comment: @nimeshjm i updated the post. How can i solved this issue based on your explanations

Answer (score 1):

you could try displaying it whitout script. i used an iframe with variable strings.

```
ifmaps.Src = "https://maps.google.de/maps?hl=de&q=" + sStreet + " " + sCity + "+(" + sCity + ")&ie=UTF8&t=&z=17&iwloc=B&output=embed";

<div>
        <iframe width="600" height="300" runat="server" ID="ifmaps" frameborder="10" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" > </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: please can you give more details on the variables used in your case. i called the goodle Map using a div id 'dvMap' . <div id="dvMap" style="width: 1100px; height: 550px"></div>

Comment: sStreet , sCity, sCity you fill them with the wanted location. sry didnt see it its german ;)

Comment: ok, please can u give more details on implementation of this in asp.net

Comment: in my case i load Long & lat from data source and use gmap to display them. but in case i dont see how you pass the long & lat values